# Reading unicode values from excel to string

Tags: python, excel, unicode, xlrd

I have an excel file (xlsx). The values are read as unicode values.

```
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('file.xlsx')
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
first_column = sh.col_values(0)
snd_column = sh.col_values(1)
```

Output is in the form of:

```
first_column=['', u'here', u'here i am', u'where', u'where i am']
snd_column=['', u'20 km', ' ', u'10 km', u'23 km']
```

Empty cells are read as normal empty strings.

How do I get output/read the file directly in strings form. like

```
first_coulmn=['', 'here', 'here i am', 'where', 'where i am']
snd_coulmn=['', '20 km', ' ', '10 km', '23 km']
```

I am looking are computationally effective method. Any tips?

Comment: Why do you *need* byte strings?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters It becomes cumbersome while doing operations on dictionary with unicode values.

Comment: In Python 2, if all you have is ASCII data you can compare byte strings and unicode values freely. Storing Unicode as dict keys then looking the values up with byte string works just fine.

Comment: Explain "cumbersome".

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
first_column = [str(v) for v in first_column]
```

Comment: If there are large number of columns, it would be make the code slow. I was thinking there might be some method to invoke something at `xlrd.open_workbook('file.xlsx')` ? Directly read the unicode values into string form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the str() function to cast from unicode to string.  Is that what you are asking?

Answer (score -1):

```
worksheet.cell_value(row_index,coluna_sample) gives me --> u'7690088954'
str(worksheet.cell(row_index,coluna_sample).value) gives me --> '7690088954'
As sugested by aestrivex
```